# Cant accept license while running kitchen test

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, chef-recipe, test-kitchen

I run kitchen test, cant accept the license, answer yes does nothing

kitchen.yml

```
provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
  always_update_cookbooks: true
  retry_on_exit_code:
  - 35 # 35 is the exit code signaling that the node is rebooting
  max_retries: 1
client_rb:
    exit_status: :enabled # Opt-in to the standardized exit codes
    client_fork: false  # Forked instances don't return the real exit code
    environment: _default
    chef_license: accept
    product_name: chef
    chef-client: 14
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to update from `accept` to `accept-no-persist` in the provisioner section per the github issue: https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/issues/1553

`provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
  always_update_cookbooks: true
  log_level: info
  chef_license: accept-no-persist
  product_name: chef
  product_version: 14`

note (via tas50 comment on the github issue): Test Kitchen 1.x does not support chef licensing. The plan is to backport the work on the 2.x branch to the 1-stable branch and release a new 1.X release with the support.